# Does the phase of the moon affect my butterflies?

Tags: flutter-starlight

I noticed when I was selecting flowers that it tells me the current phase of the moon. Does that change anything about the flowers or the butterflies I get?

Answer (score 1):

You will attract a different kind of moth according to what phase our moon is in. I.E. if you use 2 100% lunar flowers in one day, you will attract the same type of moth both times.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does. It lets you know when is the best time to use the lunar flowers. I read in the help section something similar. I haven't used a lunar flower yet because I don't have enough to make 100% but when I do I will use it to attract a special lunar moth during the full moon phase. It just makes sense right, things always happen during the full moon lol.